# Excel: Return header for searched value (multiple instances)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Preferring not to use any macros...

I'm trying to build a formula to be able to search for a specific value within a number of different columns. See mock up.

**Desired formula picture:**

[image]

In the yellow boxes I'm searching for a specific number, and to the right I'm wanting to return the heading that value belongs under.

I've tried using a formula including index, small, search but my experience with arrays is not great.

Any thoughts?

Attaching a picture of the formula I'm using now (only including 3 months). I really don't the way this formula is set up because the data import is not easy to replace. I want the data to live in the columns.

**Working, bad not desired picture:**

[image]

Alternatively, if this formula cannot be done, is there any easy way to convert the data from the desired picture into the format of the not desired picture?

Comment: Easily possible with a combination of INDEX, AGGREGATE and COUNTIF or COLUMN. I'll have an asnwer shortly after I retype all of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **Array Formula** which requires confirmation with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of Enter alone.

In B14

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$M$1,SMALL(IF($B$2:$M$11=$A14,COLUMN($B$1:$M$1)-COLUMN($B$1)+1),COLUMNS($B14:B14))),"")
```

and then copy it across and down.

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! I will incorporate it into my project. My project includes over 100 columns so this will be very helpful. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @JOney You're welcome! Glad it worked. Please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved. :)

Comment: One more caveat, is instead of searching could excel automatically populate the values of most instances. I.e. show the top 5 values that occur most frequently?

Comment: That's a different question altogether so please open a new question with your new requirement and your attempt to resolve that issue.